# Passing model object from thymeleaf to Controller after submitting

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

From thymeleaf i am submitting a form and then trying to read the model at the controller but it is not working

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/activate}" th:object="${complete_map}" method="post">

                <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
            </form>



@PostMapping("/activate")
    public String greetingSubmit(Model m) {
        System.out.println("Got the map and the siz");
        System.out.println("received size on map is "+m.asMap().size());

        return "telco";
    }
```

It is printing :

```
received size on map is 0 , despite the map size is 3 when i redirecting from other controller.
```

Comment: You are not submitting any data in your form

Comment: How to submit that ?

Comment: What do you want to submit? put <input> in your form for every field you want
e.g. <input type="text">...

Comment: i want to pass the complete object "complete_map" which is a map .

Comment: Your form needs input-elements. It's not sufficent to set the attribute th:object. Also dynamically binding isn't possible.